# Show all 6 features on home screen, or only the main 2 with the rest hidden inside?

Tags: layout, information-architecture

Let's say there are 6 different features for an application.

1. Should we show all 6 features on the homescreen for better accessibility?
2. or should we show only the top 2 features which helps the user better, and the rest hidden inside?

Which design would provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, It depends. Since you mentioned its on the "home screen". It is better to keep all the 6 feature (here I assumed that these features can be clubbed in quick navigation like left hand panel in homescreen/dashboard).
But if you going to showcase all the feature in child page(), then it is better to show only few feature/option. just to focus on user goal